# Error When Running Pyinstaller with a pandas program Limited workspace authority

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I am getting the error `Recursion Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. I have used the `sys` library and have set the max recursion length to be beyond the default 500 with no success.

I am using python 3.7 and pyinstaller 3.6, I do use a depreciated function call from a non-pandas library, could this be the issue?

Comment: The error persists even after the non pandas libraries have been removed. Curious as to what I need to do to fix this issues

Comment: It isn’t clear if you get the error from pyinstaller or when you run the generated application. Please include the __full__ error message in your question.

Comment: PyInstaller does recursive analysis (not sure if this means pyinstaller uses recursion) of imports while analysing your code - perhaps you’ve managed to create recursive imports? Is there anything in the output of PyInstaller that indicates this? Still need the full error message.

Comment: @barny I did some thorough research and using the pandas library with pyinstaller is known to cause this problem. My solution is a bit different than others.

Comment: Still don't see a full error message that you are getting...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the recursion maximum to an extremely high number of around 10,000 and the program was able to be compiled into an executable by pyinstaller. To me this is very alarming and points at some internal problems but I am testing how many pandas commands need to be invoked before the default 500 recursion step max is surpassed.

Comment: Pandas commands aren't being 'run' when PyInstaller is building the package. Did you check PyInstaller github issues to see if something similar?